# How can I get the number of lines of a text file in specman?

Tags: text, count, specman

The files.file_size() method returns the size of a file, but there is no method that returns the number of lines.

Comment: http://www.cadence.com/community/CSSharedFiles/forums/storage/69/18110/igen_stats.e.txt

Comment: I mean the number of lines a text data file, not specman code lines

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over the lines in the file, and simply count them. For example:

```
var count: int;
for each line in file "my_file.txt" do {
    count += 1;
};
out("The file has ", count, " lines");
```

Note this is not very efficient (as opposed to file_size(), it will actually read the content of the file line by line). So, in case you need to use the number of lines of the same file several times, it's wise to keep it aside in some field or variable, rather than execute this loop every time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the output_from() method to pass a command to the shell. It returns a list of string.

```
var lines: int;
var filename: string = "myfile.txt";
try {
   lines = output_from(append("\wc -l | \cut -d \" \" -f1", filename)[0]).as_a(int);
} else { 
   error("...") 
};
```